# Ubuntu Studio 19.04 - ubuntustudio-controls crashes

Tags: sound, 19.04, ubuntu-studio

This is a fairly vanilla install on an Acer Aspire E 15 about 4 years old. I've only installed the updates and vlc.

I have yet to plug in the usb audio interface for the first time. /proc/asound/card2 exists but is empty. Why are there 3 sound cards anyway? I would expect 1 for the hdmi interface and one for the on board audio.

How else can I toggle cpu performance settings?

Thanks in advance, error message below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-controls", line 597, in <module>
    us = UbuntuStudioControls()
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-controls", line 274, in __init__
    with open("/proc/asound/card"+str(x)+"/id", "r") as card_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/asound/card2/id'
```